# Second-order partial differential equation

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

[image]

I'm trying to solve this equation. Please help!!!!

Answer (score 5):

Does this do what you want?

```
ClearAll[y,x,L0];
op={-y''[x]+NeumannValue[0,x==L0],DirichletCondition[y[x]==0,x==0]};
eig=DEigenvalues[op,y[x],{x,0,L0},6]

(*{Pi^2/(4*L0^2), (9*Pi^2)/(4*L0^2), (25*Pi^2)/(4*L0^2), 
(49*Pi^2)/(4*L0^2), (81*Pi^2)/(4*L0^2), (121*Pi^2)/(4*L0^2)}*)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Credit goes to Itai Seggev [/how-to-specify-both-dirichletcondition-and-neumannvalue-on-deigenvalues/154314](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/154305/how-to-specify-both-dirichletcondition-and-neumannvalue-on-deigenvalues/154314)

Comment: Thaaaaaaaaaanks

Answer (score 4):

Another way to show what is going on.

```
pde = D[u[x, t], t, t] - D[u[x, t], t] == D[u[x, t], x, x]
```

Separate the variables

```
u[x_, t_] = X[x] T[t];

Thread[pde/u[x, t], Equal] // Apart
(* D[T[t],t,t]/T[t]-D[T[t],t]/T[t]==D[X[x],x,x]/X[x] *)
```

The LHS is a fn of t and RHS is a fn of x, so each side must be equal to a constant.  Call it `-lambda` to match your question.
The RHS

```
xeq = D[X[x], x, x]/X[x] == - lambda;

xeq = Thread[(xeq + lambda) X[x], Equal] // Expand

(* D[X[x], x, x] + lambda X[x] == 0 *)
```

Which is the equation you were after.  DSolve with just one of the conditions.

```
DSolve[{xeq, X[0] == 0}, X[x], x] // Flatten
(*{X[x]\[Rule]C[2] Sin[Sqrt[lambda] x]}*)

X[x_] = X[x] /. %;

$Assumptions =lambda > 0 && L > 0

(D[X[x], x] /. x -> L) == 0
(*C[2] Sqrt[lambda] Cos[L Sqrt[lambda]]==0*)
```

The Cosine is 0 at values of `(2n+1)Pi/2` for `n = 0,1,2...`

```
Solve[Sqrt[lambda] L == ((2 n + 1) Pi)/2, lambda] // Simplify//Factor
(*{{lambda->(Pi^2 (2 n+1)^2)/(4 L^2)}}*)
```